# The table layout isn't fully displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

The image displayed on android studio and it on the emulator are different. How can i fix this? Is there any way to fix this by fixing xml or graphically?

[an image on android studio and emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNWpg.png)

I want to add my xml here but the website doesn't allow me to do that. How can i add some code here?It says
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="253dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Llayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrl"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_one"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
                android:text="@string/one"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_two"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/two"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_three"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/three"
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_four"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/four"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_five"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/five"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_six"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/six"
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_seven"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/seven"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_eight"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/eight"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_nine"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/nine"
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_zero"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/zero"
                android:textSize="60sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:onClick="onclick2"
                android:text="Button"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO, please update your question with the relevant code

Comment: Try replacing every the height of every `TableRow` with `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Studios Design view and your emulator's screen size and dpi might be different thats why its showing diffrenet results. Try making UI that is flexable for all devices or make different layouts for different sizes.

Try something like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="253dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="6dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Llayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="60sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrl"

    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.51">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_one"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_two"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_three"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="3"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_four"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="4"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_five"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_six"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="6"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_seven"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="7"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_eight"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="8"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_nine"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="9"
            android:textSize="60sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_zero"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="clip_horizontal|center"
            android:text="0"
            android:textSize="60sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```